# How to start the cave of dreams quest

Tags: the-witcher-3

I finished the phantom contract but the two guys that are supposed to fight me never show up. I've already finished the main story line so maybe this is messing up the quest, Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this quest you have to protect Blueboy Lugos, if you have already done the King's Gambit quest he is already dead so the quest doesn't start.